# How to pass an ID of a record I want to delete to Remodal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, remodal

I have a dynamically list of records created like this:

```
Option 1 <a href="#modal" data-id="1">delete</a>
Option 2 <a href="#modal" data-id="2">delete</a>
Option 3 <a href="#modal" data-id="3">delete</a>
Option 4 <a href="#modal" data-id="4">delete</a>
```

and the Remodal window (the source for more information is here https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#remodal):

```
<div class="remodal-bg">
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
    <h1>Deleting record</h1>
    <p>
        Are sou sure?
    </p>
    <br>
    <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
</div>
```

All works ok if I push on delete, the modal Window opens but... how I know that I clicked on a record with ID 3 or... ID 2... so I can send it to my jQuery ajax and delete it in my database if finally I press OK button in modal window? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen for `click` events on your delete anchor tags. Get the `data-id` attribute value of the clicked link and use the `confirmation` event on your modal to add the current id as custom data bound to the event.

Here is some information on how this works.

> [**event.data**](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/)
>
> **Description:** An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.

Now you just have to make sure that the added listener for `confirmation` event on the modal gets removed, because the modal may be closed via cancellation and not by confirmation. You can use the `closed` event on the modal to do that.

Here is an example.

```js
var $delBtns = $('a[data-id]');
var idToDel = 0;

function deleteRecord ( e ) {
  console.log("Delete record with ID:", e.data.relatedId);
}

$delBtns.on('click', function() {
  idToDel = this.dataset.id;
  $(document).one('confirmation', '.remodal', { relatedId: idToDel }, deleteRecord);
})

$(document).on('closed', '.remodal', function (e) {
  $(document).off('confirmation', '.remodal', deleteRecord);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.0/remodal.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.0/remodal-default-theme.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.0/remodal.min.js"></script>

Option 1 <a href="#modal" data-id="1">delete</a><br>
Option 2 <a href="#modal" data-id="2">delete</a><br>
Option 3 <a href="#modal" data-id="3">delete</a><br>
Option 4 <a href="#modal" data-id="4">delete</a>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h1>Deleting record</h1>
  <p>
    Are sou sure?
  </p>
  <br>
  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
  <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
</div>
```